# Liferay 7.1 is displaying a strange error "${processor.processMax()" - Could not initialize class BundleJavaFileManager

Tags: liferay, liferay-dxp, liferay-7.1

Adding new private pages (or simply pages in general), Liferay 7.1 is throwing the exception below :

```
ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-4][LiferayMethodExceptionEventHandler:54] Unable to execute method processMax {exception=com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletContainerException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.servlet.jsp.compiler.internal.BundleJavaFileManager, className=com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.velocity.TemplateProcessor}
com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletContainerException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.servlet.jsp.compiler.internal.BundleJavaFileManager
    at com.liferay.portlet.internal.PortletContainerImpl._preserveGroupIds(PortletContainerImpl.java:393)
    at com.liferay.portlet.internal.PortletContainerImpl.render(PortletContainerImpl.java:201)

    ...
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.servlet.jsp.compiler.internal.BundleJavaFileManager
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:667)
    at com.liferay.taglib.servlet.PageContextWrapper.handlePageException(PageContextWrapper.java:173)
    at org.apache.jsp.html.portal.render_005fportlet_jsp._jspService(render_005fportlet_jsp.java:2317)
...
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.servlet.jsp.compiler.internal.BundleJavaFileManager
    at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.servlet.jsp.compiler.internal.JspCompiler.getJavaFileManager(JspCompiler.java:348)
    at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.servlet.jsp.compiler.internal.JspCompiler.compile(JspCompiler.java:113)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateClass(Compiler.java:384)
    ...
2018-10-22 21:10:05.996 ERROR [liferay/monitoring-1][ParallelDestination:55] Unable to process message {destinationName=liferay/monitoring, response=null, responseDestinationName=null, responseId=null, payload=[{displayName=Group Pages, portletId=com_liferay_layout_admin_web_portlet_GroupPagesPortlet, requestType=RENDER, {attributes=null, companyId=20099, groupId=20126, description=null, duration=0, name=com_liferay_layout_admin_web_portlet_GroupPagesPortlet, namespace=com.liferay.monitoring.Portlet, requestStatus=null, stopWatch=0:00:00.985, timeout=0, user=20139}}, {referer=http://localhost:8080/group/guest/~/control_panel/manage?p_p_id=com_liferay_layout_admin_web_portlet_GroupPagesPortlet&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=maximized&p_p_mode=view&_com_liferay_layout_admin_web_portlet_GroupPagesPortlet_tabs1=pages&_com_liferay_layout_admin_web_portlet_GroupPagesPortlet_navigation=private-pages&p_r_p_selPlid=0&p_p_auth=GrbsPdTZ, remoteAddr=127.0.0.1, requestURL=http://localhost:8080/c/portal/layout.jsp_display, statusCode=200, userAgent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36, {attributes=null, companyId=20099, groupId=20126, description=Portal Request, duration=6, name=/c/portal/layout, namespace=com.liferay.monitoring.Portal, requestStatus=SUCCESS, stopWatch=0:00:00.006, timeout=-1, user=20139}}, {referer=http://localhost:8080/group/guest/~/control_panel/manage?p_p_id=com_liferay_layout_admin_web_portlet_GroupPagesPortlet&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=maximized&p_p_mode=view&_com_liferay_layout_admin_web_portlet_GroupPagesPortlet_tabs1=pages&_com_liferay_layout_admin_web_portlet_GroupPagesPortlet_navigation=private-pages&p_r_p_selPlid=0&p_p_auth=GrbsPdTZ, remoteAddr=127.0.0.1, requestURL=, statusCode=200, userAgent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36, {attributes=null, companyId=20099, groupId=20126, description=null, duration=980, name=/c/portal/layout, namespace=com.liferay.monitoring.Portal, requestStatus=SUCCESS, stopWatch=0:00:00.980, timeout=-1, user=20139}}, {referer=http://localhost:8080/group/guest/~/control_panel/manage?p_p_id=com_liferay_layout_admin_web_portlet_GroupPagesPortlet&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=maximized&p_p_mode=view&_com_liferay_layout_admin_web_portlet_GroupPagesPortlet_tabs1=pages&_com_liferay_layout_admin_web_portlet_GroupPagesPortlet_navigation=private-pages&p_r_p_selPlid=0&p_p_auth=GrbsPdTZ, remoteAddr=127.0.0.1, requestURL=, statusCode=200, userAgent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36, {attributes=null, companyId=20099, groupId=20126, description=null, duration=997, name=/group/guest/~/control_panel/manage, namespace=com.liferay.monitoring.Portal, requestStatus=SUCCESS, stopWatch=0:00:00.997, timeout=-1, user=null}}], values={defaultLocale=en_US, companyId=20099, groupId=0, principalName=20139, permissionChecker=com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.TransientValue@7b665540, siteDefaultLocale=en_US, themeDisplayLocale=en_US}}
com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.MessageListenerException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.BaseMessageListener.receive(BaseMessageListener.java:32)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.InvokerMessageListener.receive(InvokerMessageListener.java:74)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.ParallelDestination$1.run(ParallelDestination.java:52)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$WorkerTask._runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:756)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$WorkerTask.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:667)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.liferay.portal.monitoring.internal.statistics.portlet.PortletStatistics.processDataSample(PortletStatistics.java:112)
    at com.liferay.portal.monitoring.internal.statistics.portlet.CompanyStatistics.processDataSample(CompanyStatistics.java:209)
...
```

and displays a blank page where "${processor.processMax()}" is written.

[image]

Re-submitting the page seems to "un-block" the action and refreshs the view.

Is that a Liferay bug ? I'm not sure but I think I can reproduce it randomly somewhere else :-(

Please note that I use Liferay 7.1 with the embedded tomcat 9 downloaded from Liferay official website.

Comment: Any custom code involved? If yes: we'll need it. If no: stackoverflow focuses on software development questions and you'll find on topic help rather on superuser or the Liferay forums

Comment: Hi Olaf, thanks for your answer.. No custom code envolved..BTW, I'll ask this question in Liferay forums.

Comment: Allocating more memory to JVM sorted out the issue for us.